# How to access Angular formControlName of formGroup in formGroupName (nested FormGroup) to a control

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Here's my Angular template:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="form.get('typeId').value == 3">
    <div formGroupName="options">
      <div *ngFor="let ctrl of ctrlOptions; let i = index">
        <div formGroupName="{{i}}" class="layout-row">
          <input formControlName="option" type="text" placeholder="Option">
          <div *ngIf="form.get('validateResponse').value" class="flex-100px flex-align-auto">
            <label class="material-radio">
              <input type="radio" [value]="i+1" formControlName="correctOption">
              <span>Is Correct</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

In above code, I want to set `formControlName` to `correctOption` which belongs to the FormGroup of this form.

Here's the structure of my form.

```
public ctrlOptions: UntypedFormControl[] = [];
    
public optionsArray: UntypedFormArray;

this.optionsArray = new UntypedFormArray(this.ctrlOptions);

this.form = this.fb.group({
  typeId: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  validateResponse: [false],
  options: this.optionsArray,
  correctOption: [null, Validators.compose([CustomValidators.numeric])],
});
```

Can someone please guide how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think `correctOption` must be in `this.form.options` not sibling.

Comment: re-write your code. You're using formControlName when is formArrayName, you're iterating over ctrlOptions instead over optionsArray.controls, use formGroupName={{i}} when is [formGroupName]="i",... puff there many, many errors. Think also about if you need a FormArray of FormGroup or a FormArray of FormControl.